# NTP summer date in Brazil is incorrect

Tags: server, configuration, date, ntp

I have a problem with an Ubuntu server hosted in Amazon services.

NTP summer date is incorrect for Brazil, I followed all instructions in the documentation of Ubuntu Server and followed [this guide](https://ntp.br/guia-linux-comum.php), but first and last summer dates are incorrect.

I need to sync Ubuntu Server's summer date for Brazil with time.windows.com.

Screenshot of the server through SSH:
[image]

Google is also incorrect:
[image]

[News of the official update of Brazil's summer date.](http://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br/geral/noticia/2017-12/governo-reduz-horario-de-verao-para-2018)

Windows is already updated for the new date, Ubuntu Server's NTP datetime is incorrect.

Comment: Please do not post text as pictures. Copy from the terminal, and paste into the question. Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, NTP does not care about time zones or Daylight Savings or any such nonsense. NTP distributes time in UTC. Linux also tracks time in UTC.

In addition, the *system* or *user* may choose a different time zone for software. For your user this is as simple as exporting the desired time zone:

```
[~]$ date
Sat 11 Aug 15:28:31 CEST 2018
[~]$ export TZ='Asia/Singapore'
[~]$ date
Sat 11 Aug 21:28:39 +08 2018
```

It's not a NTP problem, it's a problem with your Time Zone Data configuration. In Ubuntu this is kept in the package `tzdata`.

You should check which version you have installed with `apt policy tzdata`, and compare this with the latest [available version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata), at the time of writing `2017c-0ubuntu0.16.04` for 16.04 and `2018d-1` for 18.04. If you have the latest version, and it has incorrect definitions, you should file a bug against the package in Launchpad, explaining why the current definition of the time zone is incorrect.

So in short: your problem is not related to ntp, but to `tzdata` being incorrect for your case.

In case you manually want to update the tz information while waiting for the update, this is possible. You have to download the new release of the [tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), and compile.

```
[/tmp]$ wget "https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2018e.tar.gz"
[/tmp]$ mkdir tzdata; cd tzdata
[/tmp/tzdata]$ tar -zxf ../tzdata2018e.tar.gz
[/tmp/tzdata]$ mkdir test
[/tmp/tzdata]$ zic -d test southamerica
[/tmp/tzdata]$ TZ=`pwd`/test/America/Sao_Paulo date
Sat 11 Aug 10:49:18 -03 2018
[/tmp/tzdata]$ zdump -v `pwd`/test/America/Sao_Paulo | grep 2018
/tmp/tzdata/test/America/Sao_Paulo  Sun Feb 18 01:59:59 2018 UT = Sat Feb 17 23:59:59 2018 -02 isdst=1 gmtoff=-7200
/tmp/tzdata/test/America/Sao_Paulo  Sun Feb 18 02:00:00 2018 UT = Sat Feb 17 23:00:00 2018 -03 isdst=0 gmtoff=-10800
/tmp/tzdata/test/America/Sao_Paulo  Sun Nov  4 02:59:59 2018 UT = Sat Nov  3 23:59:59 2018 -03 isdst=0 gmtoff=-10800
/tmp/tzdata/test/America/Sao_Paulo  Sun Nov  4 03:00:00 2018 UT = Sun Nov  4 01:00:00 2018 -02 isdst=1 gmtoff=-7200
```

If this looks correct, you can run `sudo zic southamerica` to actually replace your distribution provided tzdata for South American region.

Some more information can be found in [Debians wiki page for TimeZoneChange](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges). When it comes to tzdata, Ubuntu behaves exactly as Debian, so the page is a valid resource for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I was also having the same confusion as OP, and your explanation about the different responsibilities of the different packages was very helpful.